# Cyclomatic complexity of a for loop

Tags: cyclomatic-complexity

I've been introduced to the cyclomatic complexity with two different definitions. First "the cyclomatic complexity is the number of independent paths in the flux diagram of the code" and second "the number of times you have to run the program through different paths to have executed every part of it".

However, I have a problem with a for loop where both definitions aren't compatible.

In a for loop, the cyclomatic complexity through the first definition is two. However, you'd only have to run the loop once to go trough every part of the program.

So my question is, is the for a special case or is one of the definitions wrong?

Edit:

I´ve been told that the for loop checks for the condition and it could be that it wont even go inside the loop but I had the intuition that the graph in the for loop exited 'from the bottom' so which of these two graphs would be the one?

[image]

Comment: `However, you'd only have to run the loop once to go trough every part of the program.` there is path when loop is not executed at all, ie condition is false from the very beginning

Comment: How would you write the graph of a for then?

Comment: I'm not sure how to write graph, and drawing is not supported here, so I cannot answer that question

Comment: I've edited the origonal post to include the graphs i think are the posible ones

Comment: It seems to me that if, as in your drawing on the left, you have an edge from 3 to F, there will need to be two termination tests in the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have assumed that the for loop will always execute its enclosed contents in the loop body - that is not guaranteed if the for loop termination condition is already met on entry.

There are two potential paths for that initial conditional branch as far as CCI is concerned:
the normal one where the for loop contents **do** get executed at least once, and another where they do **not**.

They are quite distinct paths through the for loop code and both need testing (unless you can be sure that skipping of the for loop body execution can never occur in your particular program).

When the body of a for loop is not executed it could leave a variable uninitialised that has consequences later.

Comment: So the correct diagram for the loop would be the right hand one right?

Comment: Almost. The conditional test means that the loop code only ever executes if that test is met. But in practice it is usually implemented as an unconditional jump to a conditional branch at the end looping back to the start of the body if required (saves an instruction). IOW your node 3 is not inside for the loop but is the very first thing that happens. It wasn't always the case in other languages though. Archaic pre-1977 standard [FORTRAN "DO" loops](http://www-pnp.physics.ox.ac.uk/~gronbech/intfor/node18.html) always executed the loop body at least once. They put that right in FORTRAN 77.

Answer (score 2):

The graph on the right is the correct one for a for loop.

In effect, the compiler inserts a goto at the bottom of the body that sends it back up to the top of the loop.

At the top of the loop, the condition is checked, and if it is true, the body is executed again.   If it is false, it skips the body and falls into the next statement.